# LaWTeX install help on Linux

Tags: installing

I am a law student trying to use the LaWTeX package.  Can anyone explain how I would go about installing this on my Ubuntu distro?

Answer (score 1):

See the [LaWTeX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lawtex/files/) page for more information.  (Most of this was taken from there.)

You have two main choices. (Others exist, but I don't think I recommend them.) There's the `TEXMFLOCAL` and `TEXMFHOME` variables, which will expand to something like:

```sh
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
```

and

```sh
~/texmf
```

(You can test for yourself using the command: `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL` and `TEXMFHOME`.)

Let's say you are going to use `TEXMFLOCAL`. Then you want to issue the following commands:

```sh
 sudo mkdir -p $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/tex/latex/lawtex 
 sudo mkdir -p $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/makeindex/lawtex 
 sudo mkdir -p $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/doc/latex/lawtex
```

Then you want to copy the various files from the LaWTeX bundle to the appropriate places.

```sh
sudo cp *.cls bluebook.sty $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/tex/latex/lawtex 
sudo cp *.ist $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/makeindex/lawtex 
sudo cp -R *doc* samples $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/doc/latex/lawtex
```

Then you need to refresh the database:

```sh
sudo mktexlsr
```

Apparently, you also need to have the `multind` and `xstring` packages installed. `multind` is not installed by default, but you can get it on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multind). I'm surprised such an old file is required....